# Searching through array of nested class objects?

Tags: c++, class, nested

I have a pantry class.  Pantry has a shelf subclass / is nested inside pantry.  I have an array of shelf objects.  The shelf class has a cookie Num and juice num variable.

I populate the array of shelf class objects from a file.  So far I have the file reading working just fine.  I made a for loop to see if the array was populating correctly and it is.  I can cout all of the values.  However now I want to make a search function so that I can find out the inventory amounts of cookies and juice.

E.G. "Enter cookie amount" User enters 5.  Program returns the information of any shelf that has exactly 5 cookies in it.

My issue is that when I try to use the search function I get garbage values returned from the array.

```
class PantryClass
{
double nums1,nums2,nums3;

public:
    class ShelfClass
    {
        public:
        double CookieNum;
        double JuiceNum;

    };

    void otherFunction2(double, double, int);
    void otherFucntion3(double, double, int, double);
};
```

Populating array

```
int main()
{
PantryClass test;
PantryClass::ShelfClass inventory[50];

ifstream inputs(input file name here (this works fine));
ifstream inputs2(input file name here (this works fine));

for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    inputs>> inventory[i].CookieNum;
    inputs2>> inventory[i].JuiceNum;
}

int choice;
cout << "Enter choice" << endl;
cin >> choice;

if (choice == 1)
{
    snackSearch(inventory);
}
```

}

lookup function

```
    void snackSearch(PantryClass::ShelfClass inventory[])
{
    cout << "Please enter the cookie amount you'd like to find: " << endl;
            int num1;
            cin >> num1;

        for(int i=0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            if (inventory[i].CookieNum == num1)
            {
                cout << " Cookie num is " << cout <<inventory[i].CookieNum << endl;
                cout << "Juice num is  " << cout <<inventory[i].JuiceNum << endl;

            }
        }
}
```

Updated it to show the 2 text files I use.  One file has info for cookie num, one has info for juice num.

Cookie num file values:  10.0, 15.0, 20.0
Juice num:  22.0, 32.0, 16.0

So at inventory[0] the values for cookie num is 10.0
The value for juice num is 22.0.

In my search function I search for 10.0.

Expected:  Inventory[0] should be selected because the class object at inventory[0] has Cookie num of 10.0.

Should then output Inventory[0] cookie num value of 10.0 and inventory[0] juice num value of 22.0.

Actual:  Inventory[0] is selected but the values outputted are numbers / values like this  0F81C3E810.0
           0F81C3E822.0

Comment: How do you call the `snackSearch` function? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Sure, one moment.  I added in what my main basically looks like under the "populating array" section

Comment: Two more things, first of all where's the `SnackNum` member declared? Secondly, can you also please give us some example of the input file as well as for some specific input also show us the expected *and* actual output?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove snack num.  I will edit in input example into the post

Comment: I think maybe it is outputting the memory location as well as the value there?

Comment: wtf are you doing? cut out the vandalism

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
cout << " Cookie num is " **<< cout** << inventory[i].CookieNum << endl;
cout << "Juice num is  " **<< cout** <<inventory[i].JuiceNum << endl;
```

You are actually printing the value of cout. remove the << cout I put in between ** and it will be all ok :)

Comment: doh.  Thanks for helping me figure that out.